How to airdrop sols in Rust test case using tokio framework
I am working over the airdrop over a particular Keypair to perform testing using rust. Signature is being generated but Transaction is not confirmed
#[cfg(test)]
// pub mod utils;
mod tests {
use super::*;
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use anchor_lang::solana_program::clock::Clock;
use anchor_lang::solana_program::system_instruction;
use anchor_lang::solana_program::system_program;
use anchor_lang::solana_program::sysvar;
use anchor_lang::ToAccountInfo;
use anchor_spl::associated_token::AssociatedToken;
use futures::executor::block_on;
use solana_client::nonblocking::rpc_client;
use solana_client::nonblocking::rpc_client::RpcClient;
use solana_sdk::account::Account;
use solana_sdk::client::Client;
use solana_sdk::client::SyncClient;
use solana_sdk::commitment_config;
use solana_sdk::commitment_config::CommitmentConfig;
use solana_sdk::genesis_config::ClusterType;
use solana_sdk::native_token::LAMPORTS_PER_SOL;
use solana_sdk::signature::Keypair;
use solana_sdk::transaction::Transaction;
use solana_sdk::transport::TransportError;
use std::result::Result;
use std::str::FromStr;
// use solana_client::rpc_client::RpcClient;
use anchor_lang::solana_program::clock::Slot;
use anchor_spl::token::{self, Mint, Token};
use simple_token_vesting::accounts::Initialize;
use simple_token_vesting::Beneficiary;
use solana_program_test::{processor, ProgramTest, ProgramTestContext};
use solana_sdk::signer::Signer;
use solana_sdk::{clock::UnixTimestamp, signature::Signature, sysvar::Sysvar};
use std::error::Error;
use tokio::time::{sleep, Duration};

#[tokio::test]
async fn test_initialize() {
    let _url = "http://localhost:8899".to_string();
    let _devnet = "https://api.devnet.solana.com".to_string();

    let commitment_config = CommitmentConfig::processed();

    println!("hellop");
    // let _client  = RpcClient::new(_url);
    let _client = RpcClient::new_with_commitment(_url, commitment_config);
    let _program_id = Pubkey::from_str("F4ftfFpMMyAWQZkahk1Rtnev1x2fLeBPTGiQx8oKF3sh").unwrap();
    // let  program = ProgramTest::new("simple_token_vesting", program_id ,processor!(simple_token_vesting::initialize));
    // let block_hash = _client.get_latest_blockhash().await.unwrap();
    // println!("bloack hash{}",block_hash);
    let _payer = Keypair::new();
    let _mint = Keypair::new();
    let _data_account = Keypair::new();
    let _escrow_wallet = Keypair::new();

    println!(
        "payer mint dataaccount escrowwallet {} {} {} {}",
        _payer.pubkey(),
        _mint.pubkey(),
        _data_account.pubkey(),
        _escrow_wallet.pubkey()
    );

    // if let Ok(airdrop_signature)=  request_air_drop(&_client, &_payer.pubkey(), 10*LAMPORTS_PER_SOL){
    //     println!("Airdrop finished! Signature: {:?}",  airdrop_signature);
    //     if let Ok(balance) = check_balance(&_client, &_payer.pubkey()) {
    //         println!("Sender balance: {:?}", balance);
    //     }

    // }else {
    //     println!("Airdrop failed");
    // }
    match _client
        .request_airdrop(&_payer.pubkey(), 10 * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL)
        .await
    {
        Ok(signature) => {
            println!("Airdrop request succeeded. Signature: {:?}", signature);

            // Retry confirming the transaction up to 10 times with a delay
            let mut confirmed = false;
            for _ in 0..10 {
                match _client.confirm_transaction(&signature).await {
                    Ok(is_confirmed) => {
                        if is_confirmed {
                            confirmed = true;
                            println!("Transaction confirmed.");
                            break;
                        } else {
                            println!("Transaction not yet confirmed. Retrying...");
                            sleep(Duration::from_secs(2)).await;
                        }
                    }
                    Err(e) => {
                        println!("Error confirming transaction: {:?}", e);
                        sleep(Duration::from_secs(2)).await;
                    }
                }
            }

            if confirmed {
                // Wait for a few seconds before checking the balance
                sleep(Duration::from_secs(5)).await;

                // Retry checking the balance up to 5 times
                for _ in 0..5 {
                    let balance = _client.get_balance(&_payer.pubkey()).await.unwrap();
                    if balance > 0 {
                        println!("Payer balance after airdrop: {} lamports", balance);
                        break;
                    } else {
                        println!("Balance is still 0, retrying...");
                        sleep(Duration::from_secs(2)).await;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                println!("Transaction confirmation failed after multiple retries.");
            }
        }
        Err(e) => println!("Airdrop request failed: {:?}", e),
    }

    // let _latest_blockhash =  _client.get_latest_blockhash().await.unwrap();
    // println!("lblock: {} ",_latest_blockhash);
    // println!("hello");
    // let _airdrop_signature =   _client.request_airdrop(&_payer.pubkey(), 10 * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL).await.unwrap();
    // _client.confirm_transaction(&_airdrop_signature).await.unwrap();

    // let _payer_balance = _client.get_balance(&_payer.pubkey()).await.unwrap();
    // println!("payer balance after airdrop:{}", _payer_balance);
    

}
$ cargo test -- --no-capture(for testing)
logs
payer mint dataaccount escrowwallet 56W71nVUKbSb6v7j5bEmhq7oGZHwikBP6RVnA6dbrpxC GwxYuA7KpzCGrdLTXg78q5rhVY7NLRuQoT32DYnvt8WG 3ysQHJqdyiMBzrDrcaFVPMETRB9h9G3XspmL9SfM2xSY 5o1JbY8pg54ovE3VB3P4BHMQsXM9t4cFXSRB6VpkSY2D
Airdrop request succeeded. Signature: c7Jz7eeS7grNQ4SKSFsFqm5vQgicoZmEffpwGAkQWsi84CxQWBijM9cTPgyRjjBDwRgJSysdLwVZ5inAzVuhViC
Transaction not yet confirmed. Retrying...
Transaction not yet confirmed. Retrying...
Transaction not yet confirmed. Retrying...
Transaction not yet confirmed. Retrying...
Transaction not yet confirmed. Retrying...
Transaction not yet confirmed. Retrying...
Transaction not yet confirmed. Retrying...
Transaction not yet confirmed. Retrying...
Transaction not yet confirmed. Retrying...
Transaction not yet confirmed. Retrying...
Transaction confirmation failed after multiple retries.
test tests::test_initialize ... ok
test result: ok. 1 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 20.05s

Blockquote

